# Is it possible to subset a PyTorch tensor using a tensor index without causing a backward second-time error?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to write a Pytorch program based on computing embeddings, where during training various subsets of the embeddings are used. I want to subset the embedding tensor using a tensor index, but when I do this I get the typical backward second time error. However, performing the exact same operation using a slice, instead of an index, runs fine. In my actual code, I have confirmed that the slice version works as intended and trains properly, etc., but new features cannot be done with only slices.

I am running python 3.10.9, pytorch 2.0.0 with cuda 11.8 on Windows.

Here is a minimum example that reproduces the error I am running into:

```
import torch
device = 'cpu'    # same error occurs when using device='cuda:0'
embeddings = torch.tensor(torch.randn([1024, 128], device=device, dtype=torch.float32), requires_grad=True)
target = torch.rand([1024, 128], device=device)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adadelta([embeddings], lr=1.0)

# alternate approach using nn.Embedding doesn't work either
embeddings_2 = torch.nn.Embedding(1024, 128, device=device)

# OPTION 1: This works
# cur_embeddings = embeddings[:512, :]

# OPTION 2: This is what I want to do, but it doesn't work
cur_embeddings = embeddings[torch.arange(512, device=device), :]

# OPTION 3: The following option does not work either
# cur_embeddings = embeddings_2(torch.arange(512, device=device))

cur_target = target[:512, :]
for idx in range(2):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss = torch.nn.MSELoss()(cur_embeddings, cur_target)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

Of the 3 presented options, option 1 works but option 2 produces an error, even though it is functionally identical. How can I make option 2 work exactly like option 1 (while maintaining the freedom to subset arbitrary rows)?

I also show here that using nn.Embedding (which I don't really want to use but could if it works) still produces the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**
Put this line inside your training loop:

```py
cur_embeddings = embeddings[torch.arange(512, device=device), :]
```

**Explanation:**
You computation graph looks like

```
embeddings ---> cur_embeddings ---> loss
            |                   |
    torch.arange(512)       cur_target
```

To backward propagate to `embeddings`, pytorch must remember how you indexed `embeddings` to get `cur_embeddings`, that is, pytorch needs to save `torch.arange(512)` for backward. However, by putting this indexing operation out of the loop, `torch.arange(512)` is freed after the first backward, so before the second backward pytorch had already "forgotten" how that indexing is done.

Your options 1 works because indexing is hardcoded as `embeddings[:512]`.